# Is after_validation method on rails deprecated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deprecated

I was looking at the Ruby on Rails documentation, and the page implies the `after_validation` callback for performing an action after form validation is deprecated: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_validation

If this is the case, what's the appropriate replacement for this?

Comment: You're not looking at the Rails documentation. You're looking at a garbage site that slurps the Rails documentation and displays outdated docs together with ads. `apidock` is the W3Schools of the Ruby world and just ends up on the top of google searches since there are so many links to it. [/end rant] The official Rails documentation is https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.1/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_validation

Comment: And the method was just moved and not deprechiated. In Rails 5 most of the basic functionality of models (callbacks, validations, etc)  was moved out of ActiveRecord to ActiveModel.

Answer (score 1):

`after_validation` is not deprecated. The reason you're seeing it as deprecated is that the page is linked to the `ActiveRecord` implementation of the method, which was moved to `ActiveModel`.

Also, as suggested by max, do not refer to apidock, the official Rails doc is https://api.rubyonrails.org/

Source: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.1/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_validation